# Simple Javascript slideshow (so passe I know), get next slides property to show in current slide

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am building a simple slideshow, I just need an attribute from the next slide to show on the current slide so I can say "Next slide: [some title]"

JS code so far

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.bannerSlides .bannerSlide');
var currentSlide = 0;

var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

function nextSlide(){
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'bannerSlide';
 currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
 slides[currentSlide].className = 'bannerSlide showing';


// Need to get H4 prop from the next slide and show it on the current slide
}
```

HTML thus far

```
 <div class="bannerSlides">
   <div class="bannerSlide">
    <h4>Slide One</h4>
    <div class="nextSlideIs">Next slide is: [next slide h4 here]</div>
  </div>
   <div class="bannerSlide">
   <h4>Slide Two</h4>
     <div class="nextSlideIs">Next slide is: [next slide h4 here]</div>
   </div>
  
  <!-- etc. -->
 </div>
```

Comment: What about increasing the currentSlide variable and getting  the next element, then just look for your H4 element inside that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.bannerSlides .bannerSlide');
[...slides].forEach( (slide, index) => {
  // get the "first" slide if there is no next slide
  var nextSlide = slides[index +1] || slides[0] ;
  slide.querySelector('.nextSlideIs').innerHTML = `Next slide is: ${nextSlide.querySelector('h4').innerHTML}`;
});
```

```html
<div class="bannerSlides">
   <div class="bannerSlide">
    <h4>Slide One</h4>
    <div class="nextSlideIs">Next slide is: [next slide h4 here]</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bannerSlide">
    <h4>Slide Two</h4>
    <div class="nextSlideIs">Next slide is: [next slide h4 here]</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bannerSlide">
    <h4>Slide Three</h4>
    <div class="nextSlideIs">Next slide is: [next slide h4 here]</div>
  </div>

  <!-- etc. -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I like that, you are just getting them all and then populated the next slide instead of on each function call.  Makes sense.  Thank you!